# Qt - how to edit QByteArray length and contain?

Tags: qt

i have a **QByteArray** like this:

```
// read file
QFile file("e:/test/test.dat");
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))return;

QByteArray ba = file.readAll();
```

Now I want to divide the **ba** variable into 8 parts. Each part must have a certain size. For example 100200 bytes. How to do this?

sorry for my english

Comment: You can use `QByteArray::mid()` function. For example: `auto ba0 = ba.mid(0, 100200);` will create the first part.

Comment: if i want divide file varibale to 8 part ( in begin to end length) and save it in ba varibale, i can use QByteArray::mid() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can split your byte array like this:

```
std::vector<QByteArray> parts;
static const int size = 100200;
assert(ba.size() >= size * 8); // Make sure you have enough bytes.

for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    parts.emplace_back(ba.mid(i * size, size));
}
```

Comment: I think `#include <assert.h>` should help.